# Backup running postgres docker container

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

I am trying to backup a running postgres container, without luck. What I have so far is a data only container, with - /var/lib/postgresql/data volume, and a main database container running official postgres images, with --volumes-from data only container.

I tried backing up /data directory of the running postgres container, and then restoring it, however then postgres run into WAL mismatch problem (also this won't work regardless according to the postgres docs).

So, any way I could backup the database and then restore it, while the main database container is running?

Comment: I think this is not really related to docker. You have to use the Postgresql backup commands to do live backups (either a logical backup via pgdump or a physical using archive mode). http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html

Comment: Yup, the PostgreSQL manual is where you need to be. Use `pg_basebackup -X stream`, or `pg_start_backup`/rsync/`pg_stop_backup` with WAL archiving. Or `pg_dump`.

Comment: and you would probably do these using `docker exec` :)